# Java keeps trying to convert my object to int

Tags: java

I'm writing up a breadth-first-search algorithm, however when i go to construct my graph i get the error `breadth.java:68: error: incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to int: v8.children.add(v8, v7);`

This happens when i try to add Node objects to another Node's `ArrayList` for it's child nodes.

I feel the solution may be one of those blindingly obvious things that just require a second pair of eyes to locate the error, hence me posting it here.

Here is my full code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class breadth{

    static class Node {

        int val;
        List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

        public Node(int value){
            val = value;
        }

    }

    public boolean bfs(Node start, int end){
        HashSet<Node> visited = new HashSet<>();
        Queue<Node> frontier = new LinkedList<>();
        frontier.add(start);


        while (!frontier.isEmpty()){
            Node current = frontier.remove();
            if(current.val == end){
                System.out.println("Path to goal located");
                return true;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < current.children.size(); i++){
                Node nextNode = current.children.get(i);
                if(!visited.contains(nextNode)){
                    frontier.add(current.children.get(i));
                }

            }

            visited.add(current);
        }

        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Create the Node objects

        Node v1 = new Node(1);
        Node v2 = new Node(2);
        Node v3 = new Node(3);
        Node v4 = new Node(4);
        Node v5 = new Node(5);
        Node v6 = new Node(6);
        Node v7 = new Node(7);
        Node v8 = new Node(8);

        // Link the nodes by setting their children. This is based off the vacuum problem

        v1.children.add(v1, v2, v3);
        v2.children.add(v2, v1, v6);
        v3.children.add(v3, v4);
        v4.children.add(v4, v3, v8);
        v5.children.add(v5, v6, v7);
        v6.children.add(v6, v5);
        v7.children.add(v7, v8);
        v8.children.add(v8, v7);

    }
}
```

The thing is, im under the impression that I didn't once specify a type as an int, other than the value variable. Everything is of type Node, what's the problem here?

I have also tried declaring the node objects differently, to no avail.

`Node<Integer> v1 = new Node(1);`
`Node<Integer> v1 = new Node<>(1);`

I can only assume that it's where im passing an integer to the arguments, however this is just for the constructor to change the `val`.

Comment: Thing is: none of those vx.children.add() calls would compile. Because there is simply NO method in the List interface named add() that takes multiple objects of the list type. The real answer here: READ the javadoc of the library classes you are using. UNDERSTAND what they mean. The compiler assumes that you want to use the two-argument version of the List add() method, and that one takes an INDEX and then an OBJECT. An index is an int, therefore it tries to convert the first argument to int. Which obviously isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, because I would need to see the stacktrace, but it appears to me, that it happens at those `add(v1, v2, v3)` calls.

The thing is, the add-method of ArrayList does not support such an adding where you just list all the items to add (I might be a bit out of date with the newer Java-versions though).

So what you rather need is to split those up like follows:

`v1.children.add(v1);`

`v1.children.add(v2);`

`v1.children.add(v3);`

or easier: `v1.children.add(List.of(v1, v2, v3));`  (props to Ghostcat)

This would also fit the problem, because if you give two arguments to add, the first would be the index of where to insert it. So here it would really try to perfrom a cast to int.

If this does not help you, please add a full stack trace of what is going wrong.

Edit: I overlooked, that you even mentioned, that it happens during the adding-process, so I'm actually pretty sure, that that is the solution.

Comment: Splitting up isn't the proper way:  Just use `v1.children.addAll(List.of(v1, v2, v3));` (assuming you are using Java11 or newer that has the List.of() helper methods.

Comment: @GhostCat yes, I agree - thank you. That makes it less bloated.

Comment: The OP won't get a stacktrace for this.  They will get compilation error messages.  There is a big difference ... especially given the OP is confused about this.

Comment: Before Java 9 you could use `v1.children.addAll(Arrays.asList(v1, v2, v3));` or `Collections.addAll(v1.children, v1, v2, v3);`

Comment: Thankyou very much Christian. This fixed my issue, i didn't realise there was a separate method for adding multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Christian is right, when I try to compile it, the first error I get is:

```
➜  stackoverflow javac breadth.java
breadth.java:61: error: no suitable method found for add(Node,Node,Node)
        v1.children.add(v1, v2, v3);
```

One additional thing you might like to look at, to add multiple items to the ArrayList at once, is `Arrays.asList()`:

```
v1.children.addAll(Arrays.asList(v1, v2, v3));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a graph, **then you should use a graph**, *not an ArrayList.*

You use Generic ArrayList Class's .add(int index, T element) method. This method adds the element to the given index of the arraylist but what you want is  add edges between to vertices.

For this aim, you may create a Graph class, use map, hashmap etc. but not ArrayList. Actually, the whole structure is designed the wrong way in your code, so I couldn't edit and give you a solution in the code. Some of the other answers are to simulate Graph with ArrayList and works but it is not the proper way(Also it may cause more confusion for beginners). You should create a new design that you only use a proper data structure. [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-graph) is a good point to start.